# Temporarily plug or cap the shower faucet opening

Tags: plumbing, repair, leak

My shower hot water faucet is leaking due to a worn out stem (or cartridge) gasket.

I need to take the part to a store to get a replacement but it may take a while and I would like to have access to running water in the meantime.

What are your suggestions on how to plug the hole /cap the opening temporarily?

[image: Closeup of the opening to cap]

Thank you

Comment: No separate shut offs, unfortunately.

Comment: While you're at the store, take this opportunity to buy shut off valves for the hot/cold supply lines to your shower. When you get home, install them while you've got the water to the whole house shut off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Written before the picture was added*
If the end of the pipe is clear, square & accessible, then just get a compression cap for it.

[image: compression cap]

It just tightens on & unscrews again when you're done. They're good enough to leave on permanently, if you need to. It won't damage the pipe end.

If what you actually have is the faucet with a bit missing, then you're going to have to go further back down the pipe. When you get to where you can easily access, then put a proper shut off in it. idk where you are located, but in the UK these are now compulsory in all new systems, and well worth it in the long run if you've got the water off anyway.

[image: shut off valve]

Answer (score 2):

Some shower valves have built-in shutoffs to do what you want but (now you've added a photo) yours does not.    Only on higher-end single-handle valves, if you remove all the trim you would find a couple of screw heads somewhere that you can turn shut.

Some shower valves have a "pressure test cap" available that allows you to do what you want, but you would also have to remove the shower head and bath spout and seal them with caps.   If all you want to do is go buy the right cartridge I don't suppose you want to do all that work.

Assuming neither of those options is useful to you, you can't do what you want.   A part that seals the open valve body *and also stops water from flowing to the spouts and heads* can only be the replacement cartridge.

The solution is to find a store that's open very late or very early, shut off the main supply and go shopping while everyone else is asleep.  Or to hire a plumber who will probably have the right part in the truck or know what to buy.   If you do that, also have them install shutoff valves if it's possible to do that anywhere.